# jQuery on click event happens multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make certain elements appear or disappear on clicking anywhere on screen.This is the code i wrote for it:

```
<script>
    var tonks = 1;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".navbar").css("zIndex", 2);
        $("*").unbind('click').click(function (e) { 
            if(tonks == 1) {
                $(".navbar").slideUp();
                $(".overlay").fadeOut();
                tonks = 0;
            }
            else {
                $(".navbar").slideDown();
                $(".overlay").fadeIn();
                tonks = 1;
            }    
        });
     });
</script>
```

But due to some reason, the elements appear and disappear 3 times per click.
I read similar questions on this issue here but all of them seem to be about complicated events on click whereas mine is really simple code.
I tried using unbind before calling click but that didn't work.
  Any suggestions?

Comment: Use better (meaning, more specific) selectors. You're seeing the effect of event propagation.

Comment: Whoever voted for closing this question, please be kind enough to give reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Use  event.stopPropagation() after handling the event, it will stop the parent dom element handler from handling the event.

Comment: That will work, but the better answer is not to use '*' and attach a click handler to everything in sight.

Comment: @JohnHascall, Agree.

Answer (score 0):

You facing the problem of event bubbling. When you are using `$("*")` it binds event to each element and when you click any child element it also fires event for the parents. Use `$(document).click` instead of `$("*").unbind('click').click` like following.

```
$(document).click(function (e) { 
   // do your stuff here
})
```

Comment: document click will handle any event which will bubble upto the document, while * the event will be applied to original element and also its parents.

Answer (score 0):

When using ***** you're creating a collection that lists every element in your page. So, you perform the bind() on all elements individually. This is why you're getting repeat calls to your handlers.

Your event bubbles up to the target element's parent, and then the next parent and so on until it reaches the top of your DOM.

```
$("*") // Don't use this
```

Instead, if you focus on a single node you'll only get one event firing.

```
$(document) // Use this instead
```

Additionally, jQuery events are namespaced - so 'click' is not as advisable as 'click.namespace'. Let me show you.

HTML: I'm creating two sets to play with

```
<div id="1" class="one"></div>
<div id="2" class="one"></div>
<div id="3" class="one"></div>
<div id="4" class="two"></div>
<div id="5" class="two"></div>
<div id="6" class="two"></div>
```

CSS: Some sprinkle so we can have some really basic style going on - in order to see something happening

```
div {width:100px;height:100px;margin:10px;background:red;float:left;}

.blue { background: blue;}
.green {background: green;}
```

jQuery: I've attached some functions via bind and then detached them again using unbind.

```
// Here we make two groups to play with
var one = $('.one');
var two = $('.two');

// Use named functions for better readability - try to avoid anonymous function
// directly attached from within your "bind". Better still use external functions
// to be more DRY - as show here 

// This will toggle blue on group one
function addblue () {
  $(one).toggleClass('blue');
}

// This will toggle green on group two
function addgreen () {
  $(two).toggleClass('green');
}

// Now we can call them against our bind function
// Noticed that I've namespaced them - which is better than
// listening to all of a given event
$(document).bind('click.blue', addblue);
$(document).bind('click.green', addgreen);
```

Now, we're able to unbind against certain namespaces - and don't have to turn them all off at once.

```
// This would unbind all click handlers
// We would only do this when we're sure we want to unbind all of them
$(document).unbind('click');

// This would unbind all click handlers on green
$(document).unbind('click.green');

// This would unbind all click handlers on blue
$(document).unbind('click.blue');

// We can go one better and unbind a namespace and capture all events within it
// Which means we'd unbind 'click', 'mouseover', 'custom' and so on.
$(document).unbind('.green');
```

Here's a working jsFiddle to get you going: https://jsfiddle.net/likestothink/me2992p5/